# Fit absolutely positioned DIV *completely* in relatively positioned parent DIV?

Tags: html, css

I want to use CSS (not JavaScript) to fit a child DIV with *position:absolute* **EXACTLY** into its *position:relative* parent. It's the EXACTLY part that's the problem.

As shown in the following image, the child DIVs fit very nicely inside the parent DIV's left/right and top margins but overflow the parent DIV's bottom margin by (what appears to be) *1px*.

[image: Illustration of parent and child DIVs]

A key point is that I've tried various combinations of HEIGHT for the child DIV. This approach doesn't really fix the problem because resizing the page moves the child DIV's bottom margin relative to its parent. So I don't believe the fix is to change the value of HEIGHT.

This is the CSS:

```
div.container{
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  margin: 2%;
  border: solid 2px orange;
  padding: 2%;
  height: 100%; /* Expands container to height of HTML & BODY */
}

div.leftSideNav,
div.rightSideNav
{
  height: 100%; /* Changing height doesn't seem to truly fix the problem */
  width: 1.5%;
  background-color: #ccffcc;
  margin: 0px;
  border: solid 1px #33bb88;
  padding: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  color: #333333;
}

div.leftSideNav{
  left: 0px;
  background-color: pink;
}
div.rightSideNav{
  right: 0px;
}
```

Here's the corresponding XHMTL:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="leftSideNav" />
   <div class="rightSideNav" />
  </div>
</body>
```

I've gone 'round in circles experimenting and trying to get the child DIVs' bottom margins to fit inside their parent ala the top/left/right margins. I've found lots of general discussions but none that specifically address how to get the bottom margin of the child DIVs inside their parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete `height:100%;`

and add

```
top:0px;
bottom:0px;
```

and you are all set. Full cross browser compatible

Answer (score 4):

Your absolutely positioned children have a 1px border around them:

```
border: solid 1px #33bb88;
```

That is the source of the overflow.

```
height:100% + 1px + 1px = 2px overflow
```

You could use the CSS `calc()` function to make the elements fit precisely:

```
height: calc(100% - 2px);
```

OR

Adjust the [CSS Box Model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp) to  include padding and borders in width / height calculations. The default is `box-sizing: content-box`. Try `box-sizing: border-box` instead.

```
div.leftSideNav,
div.rightSideNav
{
  height: calc(100% - 2px);    /* OPTION #1 */
  box-sizing: border-box;      /* OPTION #2 */
  width: 1.5%;
  background-color: #ccffcc;
  margin: 0px;
  border: solid 1px #33bb88;
  padding: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  color: #333333;

}
```

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing
- https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Comment: Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ydo1j3hu/1/) to confirm that this fixes it!

Comment: Better fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ydo1j3hu/2/ (corrected a few mistakes: `div` nodes and bad comment in css)

Comment: `height: calc(100% - 2px);` does the job perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding a box-sizing property will resolved your issue.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="leftSideNav">
      <a class="arrow" href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></a>
   </div>
   <div class="rightSideNav">
      <a class="arrow" href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
div.container { 
         position: relative;
         background-color: #fafafa;
         margin: 2%;
         border: solid 2px orange;
         padding: 2%;
         height: 100px/* Expands container to height of HTML & BODY */
}

div.leftSideNav,
div.rightSideNav {
          height: 100%; */ Changing height doesn't seem to truly fix the problem */
          background-color: #ccffcc;
          margin: 0px;
          border: solid 1px #33bb88;
          padding: 0px;
          position: absolute;
          top: 0px;
          color: #333333;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          vertical-align: middle;
          width: 25px;
}
div.leftSideNav {
          left: 0px;
          background-color: pink;
}
div.rightSideNav {
          right: 0px;
}
.arrow {
          font-size: 25px;
          color: #999;
          width: 25px;
          position: absolute;
          top: 50%;
          margin-top: -10px;
}
div.leftSideNav:hover .arrow,
div.rightSideNav:hover .arrow {
          color: #333;
}
```

Click [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bobbysingh20051/ds5b1615/) for Demo